# How to setup timezone in firestore usage tab?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, timezone, report, gmt

Not in Analysis dashboard. But when you go database then usage tab.

[image: screenshot]

I'm not in GMT-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quota daily period. It does not depend on where you are, but it shows how daily quota is accounted.

If you open the link "billing and quota usage" it takes you to GCP and than there is a link "Understanding Quotas". It directs to App Engine quotas [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas), but I understand it's the same logic. According to the doc:

> Daily quotas are refreshed daily at midnight Pacific time.

So this is information about which daily period you are currently in, and it's accounted in PDT time zone.

I hope it will help!

Comment: thanks. did a search of The Pacific Time Zone (PT) is a time zone encompassing parts of western Canada, the western United States, and western Mexico. In short it's for billing purpose and we can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

**I raised this query to Google and received response as:**

*Thanks for reaching out. This is Estefani from the Firebase Support team.
Unfortunately, there is no way to change the time zone on the usage tab. This is because it's an internal tool for Firebase to be able to monitor and should be in that time zone.
For now, I suggest using our tools to [monitor your database performance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage), and if you want, I can file a feature request on your behalf for this feature to be considered for future releases. Just give me the green light and I'll do the rest.*